# log.error() is not logging Severity error Instead logging Info

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have requirement that If I'm logging with log.error(e); I have to get Severity: Error instead i'm receiving Info.
Please help how to acheive this.

```
  @Slf4j
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
     @ExceptionHandler(SpannerException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(SpannerException ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getErrorCode().toString());
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Exception occured", details);
    log.error("Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

}

My logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/logging/logback-json-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

In StackDriver I'm seeing severity is INFO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing log entries, you should map other severity encodings to one of these standard levels. For example, you might map all of Java's FINE, FINER, and FINEST levels to LogSeverity.DEBUG. You can preserve the original severity level in the log entry payload if you wish.

You can find the list of different LogSeverity enums [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity) , for Error is (500)